# Wordpress: Order custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$args = array(
  'labels'        => $labels,
  'description'   => 'Add new Home Subnav',
  'public'        => true,
  'menu_position' => 25,
  'hierarchical'  => true,
  'supports'      => array('title', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'page-attributes'),
  'has_archive'   => false,
);
```

I have created the above custom post type supports in Wordpress, and I want to order the posts by the order property. (1 - 6). Below is my current WP_Query that I have defined:

```
    $subnavArgs = array(
      'post_type' => 'home_subnav',
      'posts_per_page' => 6,
      'orderby' => 'menu_order',
      'order' => 'ASC'
    );

    $subnav = new WP_Query( $subnavArgs );
```

I have looked around quite a bit and none of the solutions seem to work. I am not sure if I need to add more supports or if there is something wrong with my WP_Query arguments.

FULL LOOP CODE

```
<?php
    $subnavArgs = array(
      'posts_per_page'  => 6,
      'orderby'         => 'menu_order',
      'order'           => 'ASC',
      'post_type'       => 'home_subnav'
    );

    $subnav = new WP_Query( $subnavArgs );
    if ($subnav->have_posts()) : while ($subnav->have_posts()) : $subnav->the_post();
  ?>

  <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-4 cta-box">
    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
    <div class="menu-content">
      <?php
        echo get_the_content();
      ?>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php
    endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at the database to make sure menu_order values are saved and are not equal to 0?

Comment: Looking at the docs for the [orderby parameter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters), it looks like you're doing it right. What other solutions did you try? Double check that you're using the arguments correctly both for WP_Query and [register_post_type()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), and of course @mleleigh's comment above too.

Comment: @meleligh I check the database and the menu_order values are being saved.

Comment: @TimMalone, I have double checked mulitple times and I have checked how I set up the custom post types (These post types did not have to sorted by menu_order though) with other projects that I have worked on.

Comment: Can you post your full loop php and let us know where exactly you're putting it?

Comment: @mleleigh I have added the code to the question